# Return counts of 0 from mysql "count()"

Tags: php, mysql, count, limit

I have the below query running on mysql

```
SELECT DATE(field) AS day, COUNT( * ) AS totalSessions
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(field) 
ORDER BY field DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

It returns

```
day        |   totalSessions
2013-12-17 |   5
2013-12-15 |   1
```

What would I need to change on my query so that I would get the results

```
day        |  totalSessions
2013-12-17 |  5
2013-12-16 |  0
2013-12-15 |  1
2013-12-14 |  0
2013-12-13 |  0
2013-12-12 |  0
2013-12-11 |  0
```

Comment: Are there entries in your table for 2013-12-16, 2013-12-14, etc?

Comment: @Robbert no there are not. I'm hoping for a way to turn `NULL` sessions into 0 sessions

Comment: Left JOIN the table with itself.

Comment: You can't have data for entries you don't have (i.e: there's nothing to relate non-existing dates to). You can go the cumbersome route (write a stored procedure, which creates a temporary table with all dates accounted for, and joins to that), or the easy route: prefill a calendar table with all possible dates from the first to the last date you envision to _ever_ need, and join on that.

Comment: @Mihai - how would joining the table with itself produce the desired results if the date doesn't reside in the table to begin with?

Comment: @czuroski I guess i need to read the comments sometimes.

Comment: i would suggest using php to output every date, and then put in an if condition in the loop that says if the date doesn't match the value in the date column, print a zero, if it does match, then put the actual value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to store (somewhere) the dates you want to return. I think a stored procedure can help you:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getStuff(d0 date, d1 date)
begin
    declare d date;
    drop table if exists temp_dates;
    create temporary table temp_dates (
         d date not null primary key
    );
    set d = d0;
    while d <= d1 do
        insert into temp_dates values (d);
        set d = date_add(d, interval +1 day);
    end while;
    select 
        a.d as day,
        count(b.field) as totalSessions
    from
        temp_dates as a
        left join yourTable as b on a.d = b.dateField -- Assuming "dateField" holds the date
    group by
        a.d;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Remember: temporary tables are visible only to the connection that creates them.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best looking solution but worth a shot:

```
SELECT 
    FAKE.dt, 
    COUNT(YT.id) AS totalSessions 
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(NOW()) as dt
    UNION SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as dt
    UNION SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) as dt
    UNION SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) as dt
    UNION SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)) as dt
    UNION SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)) as dt
    UNION SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)) as dt
) FAKE
LEFT JOIN yourtable YT ON YT.datefield = FAKE.dt
GROUP BY FAKE.dt
ORDER BY FAKE.dt DESC
```

So you select 7 dates backwards starting today, union the results, left join the data you need, group and order by date.