# Counting the Total Results that Match a Query on a Given Date/Time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to fetch results from my DB to be used in a Google Chart. The MySQL query:

```
      $query = "
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%l:%i %p %m-%d-%Y') date
     , COUNT(tweet_id) cnt
  FROM tweets
 WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%$q%'
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%l:%i %p %m-%d-%Y');
";
    $tweets = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    confirm_query($tweets);
    return $tweets;
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting multiple entries for the same minute. How can I get an accumulative number returned for all entries in the same time interval?

Here is an excerpt of what print_r returns:

```
['7:11 PM 12-15-2013', 1],['7:11 PM 12-15-2013', 1],['7:11 PM 12-15-2013', 1],
...
['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 1],['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 2],['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 1],['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 1],['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 1]
...
```

This is close, but not quite right. I was expecting the following:

```
['7:11 PM 12-15-2013', 3], ..., ['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 6], ...
```

Also, in the second set, you may have noticed that `['7:19 PM 12-15-2013', 2]` contains a value of `2` instead of `1` like the rest. I have no idea why. Clearly, the COUNT is working properly but I'm missing something.

To describe the query in English, this is what I am trying to accomplish. I want to count all of the rows that match the users query, and I want to return the total number of rows matched with their respective `created_at` date/time.

So, at 7:19 PM 12-15-2013 there were 6 rows that contained the information that the user was searching for. The next data point, 7:20 PM may have had 0 or more results, etc. Clearly, if 7:20 had 0 data points it would be left out of the result as there was no matching row.

I plan on using something similar to [Return counts of 0 from mysql "count()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643897/return-counts-of-0-from-mysql-count) in order to fill in the missing data points. But, first I need to get this part figured out.

I've tried Google, W3 Schools, and of course the MySQL official docs but I seem to be running in circles trying to get this data properly graphed.

I'd love to hear any suggestions the community has to offer.

Comment: `$query .= " GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i')";` Remove the %s!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same format in the `select` as in the `group by`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%l:%i %p %m-%d-%Y') AS date,";
    $query .= " COUNT(tweet_id) AS count FROM `tweets`";
    $query .= " WHERE tweet_text LIKE '%{$q}%'" ;
    $query .= " GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%l:%i %p %m-%d-%Y')
```

Your `group by` is aggregating by second.  However, you don't have the seconds in the `select`, so it is producing the output string, but the count is only for one second.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

IRC #mysql threw me a lifeline and helped me figure it out. It was human error. In the `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s'"` I'm grouping by down to the seconds. I forgot to remove `%s`. After removing that, it is now properly returning the results as expected.